# aws api gateway doesn't invoke lambda function and stop at preflight

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I made a rest API using **API Gateway** from and all the routes are linked to **Lambda** functions.

For testing purposes, i enabled CORS policy on the API, using the AWS console following this doc : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

I have multiple methods on my API, GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE. The problem is, I have no issue passing through the API Gateway and invoking the Lambda function for GET requests. But for a certain reason, I cannot do it with POST, PUT and DELETE requests.

Note that I have tested the methods through the AWS Console and headers are sent back and all the routes work as expected but not from the app.

The request are made from a **React** app using **Axios** and look like this :

```js
axios.post("link-to-api-gateway/api/route", {body})
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
```

The Cloud Watch logs give this :

```bash
    Extended Request Id: ******
    Verifying Usage Plan for request: ***. API Key: API Stage: 
    API Key authorized because method 'OPTIONS /api/projects/{id}' does not require API Key. Request will  quota limits
    Usage Plan check succeeded for API Key and API Stage ***
    Starting execution for request: ***
    HTTP Method: OPTIONS, Resource Path: /api/projects/0e0d89d809d5e6b2aac42q9dc63fad2t
    Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform request
    Gateway response type: DEFAULT_5XX with status code: 500
    Method completed with status: 500
```

As I get it, the problem comes from the preflight that doesn't pass through the API Gateway, so the Lambda is just not triggered.

To avoid the OPTION preflight, I tested requesting the API from **Thunder Client** and I get this error with **502** status code :

```
{
  "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

I tried many suggestions that I saw on different topics such as:

- returning the headers from the Lambda itself
- enabling CORS on the API
- deploy the API
- set Gateway responses
- remake the API from scratch

Do you guys have any suggestion ?

I expected the Api Gateway to invoke my lambda function.

Comment: Is there an options method created in your API gateway - either by you or by AWS based on your CORS settings?

Comment: yes there is, created in the aws console by clicking "enable CORS"

Comment: Are you using `ANY` method for you API configuration? Or are there individual `POST`, `PUT` etc.?

Comment: there are individual POST, PUT, DELETE and GET requests